# Problems with sum in laravel page

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have this little problem! I have the page viewcustomers.blade.php in laravel, and I want to sum the results of column cost in the selected ID; 
I'll try to use foreach but this print the results some times

```
@foreach($prestamos as $prestamo)
    @if($prestamo->idcliente == $clientes->id)
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>$  {{$prestamo->sum('cantidadpres')}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>$  {{$prestamo->sum('totalpagar')}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

And if i use the if without foreach show me an error, then whats is the best way?

Comment: Please your controller functions and models in use

Comment: Why? I dont have problems with the functions and models...  The problem is to show the sum of the selected ID in the blade page....

Comment: This is the function

public function viewcustomers($userId)
    {
        $clientes = clientes::find($userId);
        $prendas = prendas::all();
        $prestamos = prestamos::all();

        return view('viewcustomers',
            ['clientes' => $clientes,'prendas'=>$prendas,'prestamos'=>$prestamos]);
    }

Comment: Post your code in your problem as an update, not in the comments please.